# What C/C++ tools can check for buffer overflows?

Tags: c++, c, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

I've been asked to maintain a large C++ codebase full of memory leaks. While poking around, I found out that we have a lot of buffer overflows that lead to the leaks (how it got this bad, I don't ever want to know).

I've decided to removing the buffer overflows first. To make my bug-hunting easier, what tools can be used to check for buffer overruns?

Answer (score 28):

On Linux I'd use Valgrind.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see if this codebase can compile on Linux once I can't think of anything else to fix (although, I highly doubt it).

Upvoted because someone else might find your answer useful.

Comment: It's a bit of an overkill just for buffer overflow ...

Comment: Buffer overflow is a very nasty bug because the effects are not necessarily close to the cause (i.e. it can crash 500 lines later). If the stack gets smashed you'll need all the help you can get debugging. This is where Valgrind shines - it traps the overflow as soon as it happens.

Comment: There are frontends to valgrind, like kcachegrind that make it more usable.

Comment: Valgrind might be a slight overkill for buffer overflows, but the original question mentioned the program being full of memory leaks.  Valgrind should help with quite a few other memory problems as well.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with using valgrind even if it _is_ overkill, You get a lot of extra error checks like use of un-initialized memory.

Comment: valgrind is my go-to tool for overflows, what else would you use to find it??

Comment: Valgrind does *not* catch simple buffer overflows like sprintf of 12 characters to a 10-character buffer.

Answer (score 10):

Consider using more modern data structures as a way of avoiding buffer overflows.  Reading into a std::string won't overflow, and std::vectors are much safer than arrays.  I don't know what your application is, and it's possible that raw buffers are used because you need the speed, but it's more common that they are used because that's what the original programmers were comfortable with.

Searching for memory leaks with the tools mentioned is a good idea, but they may not find all potential leaks, while using standard strings and container classes can eliminate problems you didn't realize you had.

Comment: This won’t work for C.

Answer (score 8):

IBM's Purify will do this, you run your app under it and it will give you a report of all errors (including other ones).

To kill memory leaks, use UMDH - run your app, take a snapshot of the memory, run it again, snapshot and then use a diff tool to see the allocations made since the first run through (note you must run your app once, and take snapshots as best you can).

Comment: Good to know that it doesn't run on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4):

Check on [electric-fence](http://freshmeat.net/projects/efence/), it is design just for buffer overflow ! It does not slow down the code itself (but slow down allocation/deallocation). It works and linux and windows.

It works by adding a segment with no read or write access before and after each allocated space. Trying to access this memory end up as a segmentation fault on UNIX and a memory violation (or something similar) on Windows.

Comment: Sources are [here](https://code.google.com/p/electric-fence-win32/). Apparently it's been superceeded by [DUMA](http://duma.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with /GS is it won't actually scan for bugs.  It will just alert you after the fact.  It seems like you are looking for a tool which will scan your existing code for potential buffer over/under runs.

A good tool for this, and other defects, is the Microsoft PreFAST tool.

[Information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933794.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

MS:

- UMDH.exe tool: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343
- /analyze compiler option (free from
  the latest Microsoft SDK)

Comment: Nice ! But runtime based. With a large code base *(written in C in ly case)* you will mainly test your program for the way it had been designed. An attacker can the several thousands required hours at reading the code in order to find a memory leak exploit. I would have expected an automated tool for source code analysis similar to what exist for JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one's mentioned [Application Verifier (free!)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948.aspx) on Windows. Visual Leak Detector (mentioned in another answer) is absolutely amazing for tracking many types of memory leak, but Application Verifier is top dog for tracking memory errors like buffer overruns, double frees, and buffer use after free (plus many, many more).

Edit: And it's very, very easy to use.

Comment: Nice ! But runtime based. With a large code base *(written in C in ly case)* you will mainly test your program for the way it had been designed. An attacker can the several thousands required hours at reading the code in order to find a memory leak exploit. I would have expected an automated tool for source code analysis similar to what exist for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

My vote goes to Rational Purify. Extremely powerful with a price to match. Makes short work of lots of problems and can really pay for itself. Also, is available on most *nix. Not sure about Windows, though.

Answer (score 2):

The BoundsChecker component of [Compuware's Devpartner](http://www.compuware.com/solutions/default.htm) does this very well in terms of dynamic execution.  For static testing, I'd recommend [pc-lint and flex-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/) coupled up to [Riverblade's visual lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/) for usability and reporting.  If you have been handed a new code base, I'd recommend starting out with static analysis with reasonably loose rules so you catch just the nasty stuff.  As the codebase improves you can tightent the rule set.

If you need to do this on Windows Mobile / Windows CE, check out [Entrek's code snitch](http://www.entrek.com/)

Another tool to consider if the code makes it into the field is [AQtrace](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtrace/index.asp), which basically analyses crashes on user machines and sends you the details.  (Just in case all that boundchecking, purifcation, linting, valgrinding etc.. misses something)

Answer (score 2):

My company, [Semantic Designs](http://www.semanticdesigns.com) is looking for beta testers for a runtime [memory safety checker](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) (including buffer overruns) that detects all types of memory access violations, even those that valgrind and Purify cannot.   This is presently for Windows C programs only, not C++ or other OSes.

EDIT June 1, 2011:  The CheckPointer tool has gone production.   Still C/Windows only.
Handle multiple C dialects: MS Visual C, GCC 3/4.

EDIT May 5, 2012:  CheckPointer now handles C99, including checking calls on the standard C and C99 libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a /GS compiler flag that adds buffer overflow protection. Are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Visual Leak Detector](http://dmoulding.googlepages.com/vld) - I used it myself, and it is the first thing I'd recommend for mem-leak detection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the free "leakfinder" tool on the CodeProject by Jochen Kalmbach. See my post for more details on this thread (and the other answers) on this [memory leak question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detectavoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code#45717)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows for memory leaks/buffer overruns and other runtime error detection you can use:

- Boundschecker from Compuware (http://www.compuware.com/products/devpartner/visualc.htm)
- IBM Rational Purify

I think they worth their price if you have large projects that need cleanup.