# Structure Problem in C

Tags: c

My structure looks as follows:

```
typedef struct {
      unsigned long attr;
      char fileName[128];
} entity;
```

Then I try to assign some values but get an error message...

```
int attribute = 100;
char* fileNameDir = "blabla....etc";

entity* aEntity;

aEntity->attr = attributes;
aEntity->fileName = fileNameDir;
```

Compiler tells me:

> Error:  #137: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
>           aEntity->fileName = fileNameDir;

Why cant I assign here this character to the one in the structure?

Thanks

Comment: I also want to add that if it let you do that you would in effect change the size of the struct to something unknown. And the size of a struct must be known at compile time.

Comment: What has this got to do with C++?

Comment: There is no such language as C/C++, and this question has nothing to do with C++.  And also I doubt that the OP really wants to use a fixed-size field for a pathname, as even on Win32 _MAX_PATH won't do the job anymore, since a few years already.

Answer (score 11):

You can't assign a pointer to an array. Use strncpy() for copying the string:

```
strncpy( aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, 128 );
```

This will leave the destination not null-terminated if the source is longer than 128. I think the best solution is to have a bigger-by-one buffer, copy only N bytes and set the N+1th byte to zero:

```
#define BufferLength 128

typedef struct {
  unsigned long attr;
  char fileName[BufferLength + 1];
} entity;

strncpy( aEntity->FileName, fileNameDir, BufferLength );
*( aEntity->FileName + BufferLength ) = 0;
```

Comment: Do be aware that if `strlen(fileNameDir) >= 128` then `aEntity->fileName` won't end up nul terminated. In absence of a better choice of standard library copy function, I usually explicitly set the last byte of the destination to 0 to avoid future confusion after *every* call to `strncpy()`.

Comment: Yes, such problem indeed exists. I guess it would be better to have a buffer of N+1 size, do strncpy(,,N) and set the N+1th byte to zero each time.

Comment: @Casey: Suppose you need to allocate a buffer for string concatenation. Do you really think that 1 for the trailing zero is a magic number?

Comment: @sharptoot A better alternative is to use `strncat` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265117/structure-problem-in-c-c/1265892#1265892

Answer (score 11):

- You're treating a `char[]` (and a `char*`, FTM) as if it was a string. Which is is not. You can't assign to an array, you'll have to copy the values. Also, the length of 128 for file names seems arbitrary and might be a potential source for buffer overflows. What's wrong with using `std::string`? That gets your rid of all these problems.
- You're defining a pointer to some `entity`, don't initialize it, and then use it as if at the random address it points to was a valid `entity` object.
- There's no need to `typedef` a `struct` in C++, as, unlike to C, in C++ `struct` names live in the same name space as other names.

If you absolutely must use the `struct` as it is defined in your question (it is pre-defined), then look at the other answers *and get yourself ["The C Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)*. Otherwise, you might want to use this code:

```
struct entity {
  unsigned long attr;
  std::string fileName;
};

entity aEntity;
aEntity.attr = 100;
aEntity.filename = "blabla....etc";
```

Comment: finally - some advise on using a standard string!  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You should be copying the filename string, not changing where it points to.

Comment: use strcpy(aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir )

Comment: Uff yes, that makes absolute sense. isnt it better to use memcpy which should be safer what I read once? Like memcpy(aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, FILE_NAME_LENGTH);

Comment: @Claus, no, that would potentially read from fileNameDir past its allocated length. Reading past the end of allocation invokes the demons of Undefined Behavior just as badly as writing past the end of an allocation. In this case `strncpy()` would be better than `strcpy` because it can be limited to the size of the destination. Just beware because it might not actually nul terminate the result.

Comment: @Claus: memcpy() will copy exactly FILE_NAME_LENGTH characters. If the filename is actually shorter this may cause problems if the source buffer is smaller. For the sake of safety use strncpy() - it will copy no more that the specified amount AND no more characters than actually present in the null-terminated source.

Answer (score 5):

Are you writing C or C++? There is no language called C/C++ and the answer to your question differs depending on the language you are using. If you are using C++, you should use `std::string` rather than plain old C strings.

There is a major problem in your code which I did not see other posters address:

```
entity* aEntity;
```

declares `aEntity` (should be `anEntity`) as a pointer to an `entity` but it is not initialized. Therefore, like all uninitialized pointers, it points to garbage. Hence:

```
aEntity->attr = attributes;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Now, given a properly initialized `anEntity`, `anEntity->fileName` is an array, not a pointer to a character array (see [question 6.2](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) in the C FAQ list). As such, you need to copy over the character string pointed to by `fileNameDir` to the memory block reserved for `anEntity->fileName`.

I see a lot of recommendations to use `strncpy`. I am not a proponent of thinking of `strncpy` as a safer replacement for `strcpy` because it really isn't. See also [Why is `strncpy` insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure/869895)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_entity {
    unsigned long attr;
    char fileName[FILENAME_MAX + 1];
} entity;

int main(void) {
    int status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    unsigned long attribute = 100;
    char *fileNameDir = "blabla....etc";

    entity *anEntity = malloc(sizeof(*anEntity));

    if ( anEntity ) {
        anEntity->attr = attribute;
        anEntity->fileName[0] = '\0';
        strncat(anEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, sizeof(anEntity->fileName) - 1);
        printf("%lu\n%s\n", anEntity->attr, anEntity->fileName);
        status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else {
        fputs("Memory allocation failed", stderr);
    }

    return status;
}
```

See [`strncat`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/strncat.html).

Comment: Too bad I can only give you one vote, as your rise several very good points. :)

Comment: @sbi Thanks. I have felt the same way about others' posts many times.

Comment: Good answer, but the last parameter in the call to `strncat()` should be either `sizeof(anEntity->fileName) - 1` or `FILENAME_MAX`.

Comment: @caf I originally had `FILENAME_MAX`. Then I decided it was not a good idea to have `FILENAME_MAX` all over the place and I forgot to subtract 1. Anyway, thanks for the heads up. Fixed now.

Comment: Compared to strncpy, its not much different, maybe slightly safer. All in all you still need to write the null. Ideally I would create a STRNCPY macro that would handle the tailing NULL; then you don't have to worry about an overrun.

Comment: I don't like that `strncpy` pads the target on occasion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use char* as if it was a string, which it is not. In particular, you're telling the compiler to set filename, a 128-sized char array, to the memory address pointed by fileNameDir.

Use strcpy: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: ...and risk a buffer overflow.

Comment: It's hard not to risk a buffer overflow when one uses char arrays for string manipulation. I operate under the assumption that there is some underlying reason for not using std::string, which would of course be otherwise preferrable.

Comment: @suszterpatt: There's `strncpy`. See some of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a pointer to char to a char array, they're not compatible that way, you need to copy contents from one to another, strcpy, strncpy...

Answer (score 1):

Use strncpy():

```
strncpy( aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, sizeof(entity.fileName) );
aEntity.fileName[ sizeof(entity.fileName) - 1 ] = 0;
```

> The strncpy() function is similar,
>   except that not more than n bytes of
>   src are copied. Thus, if there is no
>   null byte among the first n bytes of
>   src, **the result will not be
>   null-terminated.** [See man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

Answer (score 1):

1) The line `char* fileNameDir = "blabla....etc"` creates a pointer to `char` and assigns the pointer an address; the address in this case being the address of the text `"blabla....etc"` residing in memory.

2) Furthermore, arrays (`char fileName[128]`) cannot be assigned to at all; you can only assign to members of an array (e.g. `array[0] = blah`).

Knowing (1) and (2) above, it should be obvious that **assigning an address to an array is not a valid thing** to do for several reasons.

What you **must do instead** is to copy the data that `fileNameDir` points to, to the array (i.e. the members of the array), using for example `strncpy`.

Also note that you have merely allocated a pointer to your struct, but no memory to hold the struct data itself!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is this supposed to be C or C++?  The two are not the same or freely interchangeable, and the "right" answer will be different for each.

If this is C, then be aware you cannot assign strings to arrays using the '=' operator; you must either use strcpy() or strncpy():

```
/**
 * In your snippet above, you're just declaring a pointer to entity but not
 * allocating it; is that just an oversight?
 */
entity *aEntity = malloc(sizeof *aEntity); 
...
strcpy(aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir);
```

or

```
strncpy(aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, sizeof aEntity->fileName);
```

with appropriate checks for a terminating nul character.

If this is C++, you should be using the std::string type for instead of char* or char[].  That way, you *can* assign string data using the '=' operator:

```
struct entity {unsigned long attr; std::string fileName};

entity *aEntity = new entity;
std::string fileNameDir = "...";
...
entity->fileName = fileNameDir;
```

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that you declared a pointer to a struct, but allocated no space to it (unless you left some critical code out). And the other problems which others have noted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you cannot just use a pointer without initialising it to a variable of that same datatype, which in this is a entity variable. Without this, the pointer will point to some random memory location containing some garbage values. You will get segmentation faults when trying to play with such pointers.

The second thing to be noted is that you can't directly assign strings to variables with the assignment operator(=). You have to use the strcpy() function which is in the string.h header file.

The output of the code is:
 100 blabla......etc

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct
{
      unsigned long attr;
      char fileName[128];
} entity;

void main()
{
        unsigned long int attribute = 100;
        char *fileNameDir = "blabla....etc";

        entity struct_entity;
        entity *aEntity = &struct_entity;

        aEntity->attr = attribute;
        strcpy(aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir);

        printf("%ld %s", struct_entity.attr, struct_entity.fileName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For char fileName[128], fileName is the array which is 128 char long. you canot change the fileName.
You can change the content of the memory that filename is pointing by using strncpy( aEntity->fileName, fileNameDir, 128 );