# Exception when using strncpy

Tags: c++, string, pointers

The following code fragment ends in an exception when executing the `strncpy` function:

```
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 127

typedef struct {
unsigned long nameLength;
char name[MAX_FILENAME_LEN + 1];
} filestructure;

char *fileName;

strncpy( fileName, filestructure->name, MAX_FILENAME_LEN );
*( fileName + MAX_FILENAME_LEN+1 ) = 0;
```

Ayone an idea what could go wrong? In the filestructure I have a filename that is 50 characters long so it is within the bounds... I am really a bit lost what could cause the problem in this simple code fragement...

Comment: Use std::string unless you have a really good reason not too.

Comment: "An exception"? You are using a C function, and C does not have exceptions.

In any case, it sometimes helps, when asking about errors you encounter, to *describe the error*. *Which* exception did you get?

Comment: @jalf: It's probably an OS exception, likely an Access Violation.

Comment: Funny how this code looks pretty much like a copy of the first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265117/structure-problem-in-c/1265196#1265196 asked by some 'Claus'.
I suspect 'Robert' and 'Claus' are the same person.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't allocated space for the destination buffer and `fileName` is uninitialized. So you try to copy *somewhere*. You should allocate memory and then bother freeing it.

```
char *fileName = new char[MAX_FILENAME_LEN + 1];
strncpy(...);
*(...) = 0;
doStuffWithTheBuffer( fileName );
delete[] fileName;// free memory
```

Also if you have a buffer of size N + 1 and want to copy N bytes maximum and null-terminate the buffer you should do

```
*(buffer + N) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged C++ but the code is pure C. Why do you do it the hard way? The fact that C string handling isn't all that easy to grasp (and that it isn't all that uncommon to get something wrong once in a while even for programmers who have a good grasp of it) is the very reason C++ let's you do without.

If you're writing C++, do it the C++ way. Use `std::string`. Honestly, it will spare you many hours of debugging such code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated space for filename. Either do

```
filename = malloc (MAX_FILENAME_LEN * sizeof(char));
```

or

```
filename = strndup (filestructure->name, MAX_FILENAME_LEN);
```

Comment: malloc?? in a C++ application. please just use new