# How to change a global variable multiple times

Tags: c++

I have a global variable declared in .h file:

```
extern char Title[10];
```

when I use it in the .cpp file:

```
char Title[10] = "Asia";
```

more code:

```
Title[10] = "Europe";
```

this second assignment is causing an error `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' global variable`

How can I reassign this global variable?

Comment: Title[10] is a char and "Europe" is a string(i.e. const char*). They are not equivalent. use strcpy function to copy c style strings.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with the variable being global.

Comment: @jodag: A string is a data format (0-terminated array of `char`), not a data type (it is accessed using `char*`). A string literal is the `const`-qualified version found directly in source code.

Comment: @Deduplicator You're right.

Comment: Is this really a C++ question? The only thing C++ like seems to be the naming of the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

```
extern char Title[10];
```

Declares a `char` array of size 10.

While:

```
Title[10] = "Europe";
```

attempts to set the 11th element of `Title` to `"Europe"`.

Obviously not what you were intending...

**The C style solution:**

Use `strcpy` to copy the `char` array "Europe" into `Title`. [Here's some handy reference to `strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

You pass it the destination and source so in your case it would be:

```
strcpy(Title, "Europe");
```

**The C++ route:**

Use a string class such as `std::string`. [Here's some handy reference to `std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/)

```
extern std::string Title;
```

...

```
std::string Title("Asia");
Title = "Europe";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the char Title[10] = "Asia" line, you are initializing the array to those values. In the line where you set it to Europe, you are trying to set the tenth byte of the character array to a pointer to a constant string.  You should use strncpy or some such technique to copy into the string.

e.g. strncpy(Title, "Europe", 10);

Comment: never use `strncpy()`, it does not do what you think.

Comment: To explain what Deduplicator says, look at this Stack overflow entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure/869895#869895

Answer (score 0):

This is a declaration; it declares an array named `Title` that is of type `char` and contains 10 elements:

```
char Title[10] = "Asia";
```

This, however, is an assignment statement. It attempts (incorrectly) to assign a string to the 11th element of `Title`:

```
Title[10] = "Europe";
```

You cannot assign a string to a `char`, which is what `Title[10]` is. What you want to do is copy a new string to `Title`, and the easiest way to do that is with the `strcpy` function. Like this:

```
strcpy(Title, "Europe");
```

Comment: well, there is no Title[10], just undefined behavior

Comment: `char Title[10] = "Asia";` is a declaraton, yes, but only because every definition is also a declaration.

Comment: You're both right of course but those are rather pedantic points considering the level of understanding the OP is working at.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' global variable
```

is caused by trying to assign a string to a single char. Besides this you invoke undefined behavior before you get to this.

```
extern char Title[10]; // array of 10 char, indexed as 0, 1, ..., 9
```

This is declaration, OK.

```
char Title[10] = "Asia";
```

This is initialization, OK.

```
Title[10] = "Europe";  // 10 means accessing array out of bound
```

Access array out of bounds. This is undefined behavior.

---

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 5.2.1/1

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expres- sions shall have the type
>   “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or
>   integral type. The result is an lvalue of type “T.” The type “T” shall
>   be a completely-defined object type.62 The expression E1[E2] is
>   identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for
>   details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ]

Then, **§** 5.7/5 explains what `ptr + i` points to:

> (...)If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: It won't compile so it won't produce undefined behavior.