# Can you dereference a char pointer inside of a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I’m trying to deference a char pointer to a char array inside a function:

```
void getword(char *word)
{
    *word = "bar";
}


int main()
{
    char defword[4] = "foo";
    getword(defword);

    printf("%s\n", defword);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to get "bar" as output but I seem to get the completely unrelated string '1oo'.

Comment: Try using strcpy() instead of just an assignment.

Comment: Do you have any compiler warnings enabled? That assignment in `getword()` (`char *` assigned to `char`) should be setting off at least one.

Comment: I was actually getting a "integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" Warning I just didn’t know what to make of it, but the strcpy definitely works thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of a dereferenced `char *` is `char` — a primitive value type. In this case, `*word` is the same as `word[0]`.

The type of `"bar"` is `const char *` — a pointer type.

You are assigning the value of a pointer to a character. I'm doubtful your compiler let that happen without squawking mightily.

In any event, look into [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). Leaving aside the horrible unsafety of it all, this will work better:

```
strcpy(word, "bar");
```

Comment: What exactly makes strcpy unsafe? Are there any safer alternatives? But that gets the job done, thanks!

Comment: @qwesr, the fact it blindly copies into the destination buffer until it encounters a nul in the source buffer, without regard for the capacity of the destination buffer. As with many things in software, it's not *inherently* unsafe, _ie_ not if you use it properly. But because of its dangerous properties, it is much safer to be in the habit of a string copy function that knows about and respects destination buffer size. In some cases, that might be [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869883/1911388) for a caution.

Comment: That's the bad thing about C, you need to be careful with your memory allocation.