# Empty character constant in C++

Tags: c++

I copied this code from a tutorial to play around with. However, I kept on getting an error that stated that I can't have any empty character constants. The tutorial was in [Visual Studio 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2008), and I am using [Visual Studio 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2013), so perhaps this is no longer valid, but I can't find any fix.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyString
{
    private:
        char *m_pchString;
        int m_nLength;

    public:
        MyString(const char *pchString="")
        {
            // Find the length of the string
            // Plus one character for a terminator
            m_nLength = strlen(pchString) + 1;

            // Allocate a buffer equal to this length
            m_pchString = new char[m_nLength];

            // Copy the parameter into our internal buffer
            strncpy(m_pchString, pchString, m_nLength);

            // Make sure the string is terminated
            // this is where the error occurs
            m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = '';
        }

        ~MyString() // Destructor
        {
            // We need to deallocate our buffer
            delete[] m_pchString;

            // Set m_pchString to null just in case
            m_pchString = 0;
        }

    char* GetString() { return m_pchString; }
    int GetLength() { return m_nLength; }
};

int main()
{
    MyString cMyName("Alex");
    std::cout << "My name is: " << cMyName.GetString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

> Error 1 error C2137: empty character constant

Comment: To terminate C-style string use null character '\0'.

Comment: Did you know: If you double click on visual studio errors in the "Error List" tab it takes you to the line they occur on and it highlights the error? It makes it a lot easier to find and fix problems like this. Also, when posting to SO, please include the line number?

Comment: @kfsone in all fairness Manny did know which line caused the problem, and even marked it in the code, with a comment.

Comment: in the comments it said where the error was, but it would be put in the explanation next time, thanks.

Comment: The corresponding question for C: *[Empty character constant in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214828/)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This line:

```
m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = '';
```

What you probably mean is:

```
m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = '\0';
```

Or even:

```
m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = 0;
```

Strings are zero terminated, which is written as a plain `0` or the null character `'\0'`. For double quote strings `""` the zero termintation character is implicitly added to the end, but since you explicitly set a single character you must specify which.

Comment: Could also write `""` since string literals are null terminated

Comment: but then i get an error stating that strncpy is unsafe to use if i use the null terminator

Comment: @ssnobody well that depends, you can't write, say: `m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = "";` since `""` is really a pointer to a null terminated string, and not a single character.

Comment: @Manny the safer version is `strncpy_s` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy

Comment: however strncpy_s does not take the arguments i have listed

Comment: @Manny no but that is the safer version. But keep in mind that it is a warning telling you that `strncpy` is unsafe, not an error. And since you created the resulting buffer yourself, with enough capacity to hold the entire string, you shouldn't worry.

Comment: @TommyA True. If you wanted to exploit the string literals termination you could do `m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = ""[0];` but that's obviously much more complicated (and less readable) than the char style.

Comment: The "safety" of `strncpy` is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/q/869883/3466415. Personally, I try to avoid using _any_ of the variants of "strcpy" functions except in code that is thoroughly examined and tested (I prefer `std::string` for most purposes), and I turn off the VS warning.

Comment: sorry, didn't read the whole documentation properly, my bad. @TommyA, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about null-terminated string? Yes, you are right, such strings must be terminated with null:

```
m_pchString[m_nLength-1] = 0;
```

Comment: but then the compiler says strncpy is unsafe to use

Answer (score 1):

You've said that you *"get an error stating that strncpy is unsafe to use if I use the null terminator,"* but you use `strlen`, which simply **does not work** if the string isn't null terminated. From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/):

> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character

My suggestion would be to use null or 0 like others are suggesting and then just use `strcpy` instead of `strncpy` as you copy the whole string every time anyway.