# strncpy replacement in gcc arm

Tags: c++, security, secure-coding

Does `strncpy()` not have proper equivalent in arm which will take both destination size and number of source characters to be copied,

```
strlcpy(char * /*dst*/, const char * /*src*/, size_t /*len*/);
```

so here we have to just use `strlcpy()` and hope source string is null terminated?

MS has provided one which is perfect (at least appears to be ;)):

[`StringCchCopyN(LPTSTR pszDest, size_t cchDest, LPCTSTR pszSrc, size_t cchSrc);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647530(v=vs.85).aspx)

To the uninitiated, `strncpy()` is not secure (why strncpy is unsafe][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869883/why-is-strncpy-insecure)).

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own ones

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t nbytes)
{
    char *svd = dest;

    if(nbytes)
    {
        dest[--nbytes] = 0;
        while(*src && nbytes-- )
             *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    return svd;
}
```

---

OR

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t destsize, size_t srcsize)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, destsize < srcsize ? destsize : srcsize);
    dest[destsize -1] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `snprintf(dest, size, "%s", source);`

Note that `source` does need to be `\0`-terminated for snprintf, even if longer than `size`.