# C. A Linked list problem. How to work with linked list?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a linked list of courses with dynamic allocation. I keep getting errors. can someone tell me what is the problem?

One of the errors is:

> Dereferencing NULL pointer 'coursesList'.

Should I allocate memory to each of the fields of the struct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Course
{
    int a;
    char courseNumber[5];
    char courseName[30];
    struct Course* next;
};

struct Course* updateCoursesList(char courseName[], char courseNumber[]);


struct Course* updateCoursesList(char courseName[], char courseNumber[])
{
    struct Course* coursesList = (struct Course*)malloc(sizeof(struct Course));
    strcpy(coursesList->courseName, courseName);
    strcpy(coursesList->courseNumber, courseNumber);
    coursesList->next = NULL;
    coursesList->a = 2;
    printf("%d", coursesList->a);
    printf("%s", coursesList->courseName);
    printf("%s", coursesList->courseNumber);
    return coursesList;
}

int main()
{
    char newcourse[] = "math";
    char newcoursenumber[] = "54321";
    struct Course* A = updateCoursesList(newcourse, newcoursenumber);

}
```

Comment: You're breaching the size limits of `courseNumber`. Storying `"54321"` requires **six** slots; not five (the terminating nulchar takes the extra slot). Therefore your program invokes *undefined behavior*, and with that come the ghosts and ghouls.

Comment: @WhozCraig, indeed undefined behavior because the memory layout could suggest that printing course number would print `54321math`. I don't see how `coursesList` could become null.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I changed the size of course number to 6. but I have a differernt error. At this row: strcpy(coursesList->courseName, courseName);  The error is : Dereferencing NULL pointer 'coursesList'."

Comment: You must check if `malloc` succeeded, i.e. `coursesList` is not null.

Comment: Fixing the issue I mentioned, [I cannot reproduce your error](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e11f3c3523f92d1).

Comment: I don't get any errors when compiling your program.

Comment: In addition, you should remember to `free` any dynamically allocated memory - `free(A);` in this case. Running your code, I couldn't reproduce the `NULL` pointer error -- but you should always check the return value of `malloc` as @paul points out, e.g. `if (coursesList == NULL) { return NULL; }`.

Comment: Also aside: use `strncpy` instead -- it is safer, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy) post.

Comment: @costaparas The accepted answer at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy) you suggested has a 20% down-vote.  The higher rated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258577/2410359) encourages a non-`strncpy()` solution.  `strncpy()` is not really safer - it trades one set of problems for another.

Comment: @Netanel Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @chux that's very true, thanks for pointing this out. Though `strncpy` isn't perfect is still has merit over `strcpy` since it *forces* the programmer to *think* about the size of the buffers; oftentimes that's enough to catch issues early on. But using `strcat` to do a copy is more cryptic than it should be. Perhaps `snprintf` would be better overall.

Comment: @costaparas I'd consider using `char *courseName;` and later `coursesList->courseName = strdup(courseName);`

Comment: @chux that's also suitable, assuming the struct definition is allowed to change here, and the memory is freed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1. input to the function is a char array, not a string, strcpy will happen till it find a a "\0".
2. Please use strncpy with array size to avoid crash, and overwriting of data or corrupting other fields in structure.
3. courseNumber size if not enough to hold 5 char string plus "\0"
   ,\0" is required for string opeartions otherwise should print char's in array. keeping value 5 will give output

   ```
    2
    math
    54321math
   ```
4. used "size()-1" intentionally to add "\0" in stncpy , incase if input char array donot have a "\0" will be placed one by memset and stncpy.

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct Course
    {
        int a;
        char courseNumber[6];
        char courseName[30];
        struct Course* next;
    };

    struct Course* updateCoursesList(char courseName[], char courseNumber[]);

    struct Course* updateCoursesList(char courseName[], char courseNumber[])
    {
        struct Course* coursesList = (struct Course*)malloc(sizeof(struct Course));
        if (coursesList == NULL) {
            return coursesList;
        }
        memset(coursesList, 0, sizeof(struct Course));

        strncpy(coursesList->courseName, courseName,    sizeof(coursesList->courseName)-1);
        strncpy(coursesList->courseNumber,courseNumber, sizeof(coursesList->courseNumber)-1);
        coursesList->next = NULL;
        coursesList->a = 2;
        printf("%d\n", coursesList->a);
        printf("%s\n", coursesList->courseName);
        printf("%s\n", coursesList->courseNumber);
        return coursesList;
    }


    int main()
    {
        char newcourse[] = "math\0";
        char newcoursenumber[] = "54321\0";
        struct Course* A = updateCoursesList(newcourse, newcoursenumber);
        // do operations here

        // free before exit
        if (A != NULL) {
            free(A);
            // good practice to set vale to null after free
            A = NULL;
        }
        return 0;
    }
   ```

Comment: `strncpy()` is not enough to insure `printf("%s\n", coursesList->courseName);` works.

Comment: size is kept as "sizeof(coursesList->courseNumber)-1" for strncpy, array is set to "0" and this will write one char less than array size, make sure there is a termination char.

Comment: True.  (the -1, far to the right) was not visible in my screen w/o scrolling, yet it does maintain the null character termination as you say.  See also [Why is strncpy insecure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845959/2410359),

Comment: Please remember to free all allocated memory when posting "corrected" code. Also, you [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) need to cast the return value of malloc. And also, its more correct to compare the return value with the `NULL` macro rather than `0`.