# Why is strtok() Considered Unsafe?

Tags: c, security, strtok

What feature(s) of `strtok` is unsafe (in terms of buffer overflow) that I need to watch out for?

What's a little weird to me is that `strtok_s` (which is "safe") in Visual C++ has an extra "context" parameter, but it looks like it's the same in other ways... is it the same, or is it actually different?

Comment: Maybe because both arguments of strtok are pointer to char, so strtok may not reach any terminator character overflowing any local buffer?

Comment: @0verbose: Hm... but isn't that true with all C strings?

Comment: You can look at the implementation: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strtok.c?rev=1.6&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup . I'll have a look too.

Comment: On a side note, why still use this when there is [strsep](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strsep.3.asp)

Comment: I think the context in strtok_s is to make it thread safe, like strtok_r

Comment: @Mel: Because I'm using Windows. :P
@Splat: Ah, that makes sense, seems like it's the reason.

Comment: @mehrdad So drop it in your libutil/libcompat. [Look](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/8/lib/libc/string/strsep.c?revision=196045&view=markup) at how small it is.

Comment: See detailed info on why strtok is bad at [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588170/is-strtok-broken-or-just-tricky/28588171)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According with the strtok_s section of [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1173.pdf):

> 6.7.3.1 The strtok_s function The strtok_s function fixes two problems
>   in the strtok function:
>
> 1. A new parameter, s1max, prevents strtok_s from storing outside of the
>      string being tokenized. (The string
>      being divided into tokens is both an
>      input and output of the function since
>      strtok_s stores null characters into
>      the string.)
> 2. A new parameter, ptr, eliminates the static internal state that
>      prevents strtok from being re-entrant
>      (Subclause 1.1.12). (The ISO/IEC 9899
>      function wcstok and the ISO/IEC 9945
>      (POSIX) function strtok_r fix this
>      problem identically.)

Comment: +1 I hadn't seen that document, seems to explain the answer precisely. :)

Comment: Note that this specification of `strtok_s()` is from (optional) Annex K of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, and its definition is different from the Microsoft specification of [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx).

Comment: `strtok_s` is not supported by glibc, see also [Finding Tokens in a String # strsep](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#index-strsep) and [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980) and [strtok_s is undefined on os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832455) and [C-string alternatives to strtok_r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474762)

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing unsafe about it.  You just need to understand how it works and how to use it.  After you write your code and unit test, it only takes a couple of extra minutes to re-run the unit test with valgrind to make sure you are operating withing memory bounds.  The man page says it all:

> **BUGS**
>
> Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
> - The identity of the delimiting character is lost.
> - The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.  Use `strtok_r()` if this matters to you.

Comment: I made a minor edit regarding `strtok_s`... do you happen to know how it's different?

Comment: I am not familiar with that one, but it sounds like strtok_r. If you are tokenizing two or more strings at the same time, then you need one of these.  If you are only dealing with one, then there is no need to use it.

Comment: To clarify more, strtok keeps a hidden statis reference into your string.  If you are calling it with more than one string the reference will be incorrect.  strtok_r/s forces you to provide the reference to the function.

Comment: It may not be *you* who's running `strtok` in another thread. It could be your plugin. Or maybe your code gets used in a library that runs in another thread from the main app that also uses `strtok`. Or maybe you just decide to make your code multithreaded some day after you've forgotten that there's a `strtok` call in there.

Comment: _There is nothing unsafe about it._  Remove that sentence.  You literally quoted the section in the man page that says it's not thread safe.

Answer (score 8):

strtok is safe in Visual C++ (but nowhere else), as it uses thread local storage to save its state between calls. Everywhere else, global variable is used to save strtok() state.

However even in VC++, where strtok is thread-safe it is still still a bit weird - you cannot use strtok()s on different strings in the same thread at the same time. For example this would not work well:

```
     token = strtok( string, seps );
     while(token)
     {
        printf("token=%s\n", token)
        token2 = strtok(string2, seps);
        while(token2)  
        {
            printf("token2=%s", token2);
            token2 = strtok( NULL, seps );
        }
        token = strtok( NULL, seps );
     }
```

The reason why it would not work well- for every thread only single state can be saved in thread local storage, and here one would need 2 states - for the first string  and for the second string. So while strtok is thread-safe with VC++, it is not reentrant.

What strtok_s (or strtok_r everywhere else) provides - an explicit state, and with that strtok becomes reentrant.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a properly null terminated string; you will end up in a buffer overflow.  Also note (this is something that I learned the hard way) strtok does NOT seem to care about internal strings.  I.E. having "hello"/"world" will parse "hello"/"world" whereas "hello/world" will parse into "hello world".  Notice that it splits on the / and ignores the fact that it is within a parenthesis.