# Split Function c++

Tags: c++, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

I need a function of split.

has to work like this:

```
buffer = split(str, ' ');
```

I searchead a split functions, tryed boost libs, and all works bad :/

Comment: Now that's a sorry thing. What can we help you with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried?

Comment: What type is buffer? Do you want it from a string to an array? To vector? What?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c
See @EvanTeran's solution

Comment: @H2CO3 Cant you see? This guy need a split function that works well! Lets go find it!

Comment: buffer is vector, str is string

Answer (score 1):

strtok() from standard c library is pretty good and does what you are looking for. Unless you are keen on using it from multiple threads and worried about function not being re entrant which i don't suspect is the case here.

P.S. Above assumes you have a character array as input. If it was a c++ string, still you can use string.c_str to get the c string before using strtok

Answer (score 1):

The [boost lib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) is supposed to work as well.

Use it like so:

```
vector <string> buffer;
boost::split(buffer, str_to_split, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

**Added**:
Make sure to include the algorithm:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

Print it to the std::cout like so:

```
vector<string>::size_type sz = buffer.size();
cout << "buffer contains:";
for (unsigned i=0; i<sz; i++)
cout << ' ' << buffer[i];
cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) is what you're looking for.

It allows you to always return the first sub string delimited by given character(s):

```
char *string = "Hello World!";
char *part = strtok(string, " "); // passing a string starts a new iteration
while (part) {
    // do something with part
    part = strtok(NULL, " "); // passing NULL continues with the last string
}
```

Note that this version must not be used in several threads at once (there's also a version (`strtok_s()`, [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999418/why-is-strtok-considered-unsafe)) which has an additional parameter to make it work in a parallelized environment). This is also true for cases where you'd like to split a substring within a loop.