# Store words in char array C language

Tags: c, arrays, split

I have this code:

```
char *pch;
pch = strtok(texto," ");

while (pch != NULL)
{
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

My "texto" variable have something like "This is my text example".

And i need to store each value comming from pch in while, in an array of characteres, but i really dont know how to do it.

I need something like that, each value in array will have a word, so:

"This is my text example".

```
Array[0][20] = This;

Array[1][20] = is;

Array[2][20] = my;

Array[3][20] = text;

Array[4][20] = example;
```

The `pch` in while having all these words already split, but I don't know how to add into a char array, or how I will declare him too.

Comment: By using `strcpy` - at the start of the `while` loop, before the next call to `strtok`. How to declare him? `char Array[MAXWORDS][MAXWORDLEN+1];`

Comment: `strcpy(Array[i++], pch);`

Comment: But this Array[i++], how i can declare with the exat size of words i need ?

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/vJhb7u)

Comment: For a simple 2-D array, all word storage has the same max length. The case where the storage length is variable, is more complicated, go there later.

Comment: Don't use `strtok`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTRLEN 20
#define MAXWORD 6

int main(void)
{
    char arr[MAXWORD][MAXSTRLEN+1] = {0};
    char str[] ="This is my text example";
    char *pch;
    int i = 0;
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL && i < MAXWORD)
    {
        strncpy(arr[i++], pch, MAXSTRLEN);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recommend `while (pch != NULL)` --> `while (i < 6 && pch != NULL)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, good suggestion - MAXWORD added to define number of token.

Comment: I've always liked `for (pch=strtok(str," "); i < MAXWORD && pch; pch=strtok(NULL, " \n")) strncpy(arr[i++], pch, MAXSTRLEN);` Either is fine, with the `for` you handle the initial and all subsequent calls in the one expression of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Use `strcpy` to copy `pch` to character array.

```
char str[] ="This is my text example";
char *pch;
int i = 0;
pch = strtok (str," ");
char a[10][20];
while (pch != NULL)
{   
  strcpy(a[i++], pch);
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

And as @stackptr has suggested dont use `strtok` and instead use `strtok_r` . [For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336831/why-should-strtok-be-deprecated/) on this.