# Conversion of MIPS lw instruction

Tags: mips

I have been using strtok to split the string of various instructions. I'm struck at splitting the offset for instruction as shown below

lw $2,100($2)

how to split and store into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strtok` is terrible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336831/ddg#44336960): it overwrites the input string, so if you give it `" ,()"` for delimiters, as it does its work, it wipes out the actual delimiting characters of your original string, and you'll not otherwise know what delimiter was found.  On the other hand, if you give it just one delimiter character, then it doesn't separate enough.

Recommend to avoid `strtok`, and write your own code to go character by character — you'll have full control over what tokens are found when, and will also know as you find various delimiters.

Do this by initializing a char pointer (`char *p`) to the beginning of the line, and advancing it one character at a time (`p++`).  Skip optional blank characters, then an opcode, then skip optional blanks, then a register name, optional blanks, optional comma, optional integer, open paren, optional blanks, register name, optional blanks, close paren, optional blanks and comment.

In the cited answer, Eric Lippert recommends writing an immutable lexer, but to be clear, a lexer is not required to parse things — a parse can work directly on characters — and as assembly language is generally fairly simple, I suggest just doing the above in sequence, character by character.