# strtok_s is undefined on os x

Tags: c, string, macos, clang, tr24731

I'm trying to use the C11 function [strtok_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), which is supposed to be defined in `<string.h>`, but clang is giving me a linking error when I try to use it. Compiling this program:

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char * buffer;
    char * state;
    rsize_t strmax = 0;
    char * fpl = strtok_s(buffer, &strmax, "\n", &state);
}
```

Gives me this error:

```
repro.c:7:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_s' is invalid in
  C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    char * fpl = strtok_s(buffer, &strmax, "\n", &state);
                 ^
repro.c:7:9: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
  'char *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    char * fpl = strtok_s(buffer, &strmax, "\n", &state);
           ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_strtok_s", referenced from:
  _main in repro-3dcfc9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using clang 8.1.0 on OS X 10.12.6. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Buffer is not set to point to any memory that the application owns.  The result of the call to `strtok_s()` is undefined behavior and could lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest 1) set the value in `Buffer` to point to a character array that the application owns.  2) Initialize the character array to a known string.

Comment: See also [Do you use the TR-24731 "safe" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions) — and note that the `strtok_s()` defined in Annex K of the C11 standard does not match either `strtok_s()` as implemented on Windows or `strtok_r()` as implemented for POSIX systems — though the Windows `strtok_s()` and POSIX `strtok_r()` are essentially equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtok_s` is optional in C11; honestly only Windows implements it.  Use [`strtok_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) on POSIX systems.

Comment: And Windows doesn't even implement the bounds-checking interfaces in quite the same way that C11's Annex K describes (e.g. there is no `set_constraint_handler_s` function; instead, you must use the MSVC-specific `_set_invalid_parameter_handler` function, which takes a completely different set of arguments).

Comment: it is weird to see `strtok_s()` listed in [C17 standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) but you still cannot use it even you already define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`  prior to including `<string.h>` , I work with Linux so `strtok_r`  is probably the only alternative :/

Comment: `strtok_r` is unsafe, its banned from the git codebase. on unix, an alternative is [strsep](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#index-strsep). see also [What are the differences between strtok and strsep in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok:

> As all bounds-checked functions, `strtok_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant `1` before including `string.h`.

Comment: Thanks so much, can't believe I missed this