# C-string alternatives to strtok_r() and strsep() that don't modify the original string pointer?

Tags: c, split, c-strings, strtok, strsep

I was taking a look at the 2 C-string functions, strtok_r() and strsep(), and noticed both
functions modify the location of the original string passed in.

Are there any other C-string functions that don't modify the original string passed in?

In my application, the original string is dynamically allocated, so I wish to free the original
string after the parsing is done.

An example with strtok_r()

```
int main(){
    char * str = strdup("Tutorial and example");
    char* token;
    char* rest = str;
    
    printf("%s\n", rest);
    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest)))
        printf("%s\n", token);
    printf("\n%s\n",str);
    return(0);
}
```

Output

```
Tutorial and example                                                                                                                                                        
Tutorial                                                                                                                                                                    
and                                                                                                                                                                         
example                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                            
Tutorial
```

In the very last line, I wish for str to point to the unmodified cstring "Tutorial and example".

A similar output would have occured with strsep() as well.

```
int main(){
    char * str = strdup("Tutorial and example");
    char* token;
    char* rest = str;

    printf("%s\n", rest); 
    while ((token = strsep(&rest, " ")))
        printf("%s\n", token);
    if (rest != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", rest);
        
    printf("%s\n", str); 
    return(0);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Make a copy of the string and then use one of those functions.

Comment: `strpbrk` `strchr` `strcmp` `strspn` `strcspn` but anyway, so just `char* rest = strdup(str);`?

Comment: @Barmar OP already copies the string, they are simply confused when observing `strtok`'s result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding `strtok_r`. It does not change the *location* of the original string, moreover, it can not - the function can not change the value of the pointer passed into it and make this change visible to the calling code.

What it can and will do is modifying the **contents** of the string itself, by replacing tokens with `nul`-terminators. So to answer your original question:

> In my application, the original string is dynamically allocated, so I
> wish to free the original string after the parsing is done.

You do not have to do anything special. You can and should free original string after you are done with it.

You are seeing a single word `Tutorial` printed simply because the next character was replaced with `nul`-terminator and `printf` stop there. If you are to inspect the string character by character, you will see that it otherwise have remained intact.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I originally thought that when `free` is called on a C-string, it would only free the section up to the nul-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Though the mentioned string functions change the original string nevertheless the pointer `str` points to the dynamically allocated memory and you may use it to free the allocated memory.

if you do not want to change the original string you can use standard C string functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Tutorial and example";
    const char *separator = " \t";
    
    puts( s );
    
    for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, separator );
        
        const char *prev = p;
        
        p += strcspn( p, separator );
        
        int width = p - prev;
        
        if ( width ) printf( "%.*s\n", width, prev );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Tutorial and example
Tutorial
and
example
```

Using this approach you can dynamically allocate memory for each extracted substring.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Tutorial and example";
    const char *separator = " \t";
    
    puts( s );
    
    size_t n = 0;
    char **a = NULL;
    int success = 1;
    
    for ( const char *p = s; success && *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, separator );
        
        const char *prev = p;
        
        p += strcspn( p, separator );
        
        if ( p - prev != 0 )
        {
            char *t = malloc( p - prev + 1 );
            
            if ( ( success = t != NULL ) )
            {
                t[p - prev] = '\0';
                memcpy( t, prev, p - prev );
            
                char **tmp = realloc( a, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );
                
                if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
                {
                    a = tmp;
                    a[n++] = t;
                }
                else
                {
                    free( t );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        puts( a[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free( a[i] );
    }
    
    free( a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
Tutorial and example
Tutorial
and
example
```